# Complex vs Real Spin Representations

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory

In any book about spin geometry, both real and complex representations of the Lie group $Spin(n)$ are described. In which situations are each useful? Are there some properties of one which the other doesn't have that we need for some reason?

For example, to construct Seiberg-Witten invariants, we usually use the complex spin representation... can we use the real one if we want?